# MIPS - Accessing an array

Tags: arrays, recursion, mips

So i have an array, that is filled previously with 1's or 0's, whenever i try to compile this code MIPS gives me a syntax error, could someone explain what this syntax error is? I'm having trouble understanding why you can't access the array like that, of course $t1 is a counter for the index, which increments up through 100

```js
   slti $t7, prim_flag($t1), 1 # checks if prim_flag ($t1) < 1 stores 1 if so stores 0 if not
beq $t7, 0, print_numbers # checks if the value in $t7 is 0, if so jump to end_game
```

and the array:

```js
.data
 test: .asciiz   "Printing numbers:"
 test_2: .asciiz "Before loop"
 space: .asciiz  " "
 done: .asciiz "\n Done printing the array"

 numbers:
  .word 0:210
 numbers_size:
  .word 210
 prim_flag:
  .word 1:210
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid operand combination for `slti` is `register,register,immediate`. You're trying to use `register,memory,immediate`, and there's simply no such version of `slti` in the MIPS instruction set.

Practically every time you need to perform an operation on some data in memory in MIPS assembly, you first have to load that data into a register using `lb/lh/lw`; then you can perform the operation you need on that register; and finally write some result back to memory if necessary.

---

Also note that the constant to the left of the parentheses in `prim_flag($t1)` is an *offset*, not the base address. The base address is the part that's inside the parentheses, and has to be a register. And since the offset has to fit in 16 bits due to how MIPS instructions are encoded, it's possible that `prim_flag` won't fit. So you might have to load the address of `prim_flag` into some register, then add that register plus `$t1` and store the sum in a third register, and then read from memory using that last register as the base address.